# Some fetched urls trigger reload in react useEffect

Tags: reactjs, fetch, use-effect

I've got a basic react component with an `useEffect` hook

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
   <App />,
   document.getElementById('root'),
);

function App() {
   useEffect(() => {
      fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/stuff');
   }, []);

   return (
      <main>
         Test
      </main>
   );
}
```

There is nothing special about it. It just fetches like shown and does nothing with it.

The weird part is, that some urls like the one shown will trigger a loop of page reloads, without throwing an error.
Urls like `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1` work fine.

I tried the `fetch` method as seen above, as well as `XMLHttpRequest`. It's the same result.

Regarding the first url:

- it's reverse proxy that exists for the purpose of preventing cors errors, while using other APIs locally.
- it send JSON data, which we're able to see briefly before the page reloads.

I sadly cannot show you an example setup to reproduce this error.

I think React.useEffect is somehow responsible for this behavior, because it works without using react. I couldn't find anything about this issue. Would be happy to knwo what's causing this and how to prevent it.

The application runs on an url like `http://localhost:3000/build`

kind regards

EDIT:
github issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20683

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit of this behavior. I'm developing in vscode and in there I'm using "Live Server" from Ritwick Dey to host builds locally without much of a hassle.

This Live Server triggers the page reload. That's why I don't see any errors or something.

React has nothing to do with it directly.